# Create a function that can remove characters and multiply figures

Tags: python, pandas, operation

I need to build a function named `format_adjustment` that can remove a "%" character, and multiply any value more than 0 by 100. (Also, any negative values remain the same).

Example dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A','B','C'], 'col2':[-0.42%,0.091,0.0023%], 'col3': [30, 10,20]})

   col1     col2   col3
0     A   -0.42%     30
1     B    0.091     10
2     C  0.0023%     20
```

Expected outcome for col2 would look like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A','B','C'], 'col2':[-0.42,0.091,0.0023], 'col3': [30, 10,20]})

   col1     col2   col3
0     A    -0.42     30
1     B      9.1     10
2     C     0.23     20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def format_adjustment(col2):
    # remove % and convert to float
    col2 = float(col2.replace('%', ''))
    # multiply by 100 if > 0
    if col2 > 0:
         col2 *= 100
    return col2

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A','B','C'], 'col2':['-0.42%','0.091','0.0023%'], 'col3': [30, 10,20]})
# apply format_adjustment function
df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: format_adjustment(x))
```

output:

> ```
> >>> df
>   col1  col2  col3
> 0    A -0.42    30
> 1    B  9.10    10
> 2    C  0.23    20
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype('str').str.replace('%', '').astype('float')
df['col2'] *= np.where(df['col2'] > 0, 100, 1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  col1  col2  col3
0    A -0.42    30
1    B  9.10    10
2    C  0.23    20
```